# Android: What is drt and drt_ts doing in my preference?

Tags: android

When I register a preference change listener on my own preference, I get these two key
1. drt
2. drt_ts

I have searched my application and there's no these two key in my preference.

Is this added by Android automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I have searched through the Android source code, and it seems that DRT has something with testing. I suppose you are building a Debug version. Try to build a Release version and see if it disappears, but I don't think it matters that much.
Also, after some Googling, it seems that many hobby application from XDA-Developers has this preference, this further confirms my thought.

Answer (score 0):

Google Admob SDK seems to be adding `drt` and `drt_ts` keys to the shared preferences.